# Cadastral data data.gouv.fr

Tags: data, fields-attributes, france

Someone has already worked with cadastral data on the data.gouv.fr website

I need to have information about the attributes of the "Buildings" layer.

Is there any information among the data provided or any other file to determine the use of the building?

Example: Indiv. housing, Collective housing Bureaux Bat. Industrial....

There is an attribute'Type' with the values'01' and'02' but no information is provided to give the meaning of each value.

Comment: Please ask questions in English, since we're an international community and everyone should be able to participate when it comes to asking and answering, thank you. I'm sure there is somewhere on the website a manual explaining the codes. Have you searched for it?

Comment: yes ; I have but nothing, no information is given about attributs

Comment: For questions about open data I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Probably the best contact would be the developers themselves `The team working on this platform is also reachable by e-mail: info@data.gouv.fr`

Comment: Can you give the link to the data you downloaded? There isn't a metadata page, or linked with the dataset? Who is the provider?

Comment: here is the link : https://cadastre.data.gouv.fr/data/etalab-cadastre/2019-10-01/shp/departements/ --> the numbers represent departments codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to http://www.construires.fr/comprendre-la-the-caster-site-sale-gender/

type '01' -> hard building (the main buildings of the land such as houses, buildings, businesses or warehouses. They can also represent some residential annexes such as verandahs or indoor pools.)

type '02' -> light building (it refers to non-main buildings such as sheds, garages, parking spaces built in hard and some small annexes such as garden sheds or hutches / henhouses. For multi-storey buildings, buildings sometimes illustrate roof or balcony upgrades.)