# Accessing INSPIRE cadastral data through QGIS

Tags: qgis, europe, germany, inspire

I am at the Germany specific Cadastral parcels page on INSPIRE Geoportal, [here](https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/results.html?country=de&view=details&theme=cp): [image]

I click on the first entry, [ALKIS Berlin](https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/download_details.html?view=downloadDetails&resourceId=%2FINSPIRE-4fed3eb0-06fa-11ea-8480-525400695e9c_20210629-164602%2Fservices%2F1%2FPullResults%2F6801-6820%2Fdatasets%2F4&expandedSection=metadata). Then [Download Options](https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/download_details.html?view=downloadDetails&resourceId=%2FINSPIRE-4fed3eb0-06fa-11ea-8480-525400695e9c_20210629-164602%2Fservices%2F1%2FPullResults%2F6801-6820%2Fdatasets%2F4&expandedSection=metadata#download-options). I am presented with a list of "Get Data Set" links:

[image]

However, if I click on one of them, I get:

[image]

**How do I use QGIS to access such a dataset?**

The above case was just an example, there are many other datasets on INSPIRE Geoportal, which is advised to be downloaded through QGIS.

---

Similar but different questions:

[Cadastral data data.gouv.fr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341089/cadastral-data-data-gouv-fr)

[How to access WFS DATA through a proxy in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231449/how-to-access-wfs-data-through-a-proxy-in-qgis)

Based on these, I believe my question is on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_alkis_bauwerkelinien?request=getcapabilities&service=wfs&version=2.0.0
```

[image]

in QGIS WFS

[image]

Note a large dataset (a strong/fast internet connection required as there is a lot of data here).

If you can export to a local file after fully loaded

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the link (`https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_alkis_bauwerkelinien?typenames=fis:s_wfs_alkis_bauwerkelinien&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&count=10&version=2.0.0&namespaces=xmlns(fis,)`)
you will see `count=10&` in there - simply remove that parameter and paste it into your browser bar.

But using QGis will be much easier.