Seeking open data for land parcels in Germany
I am looking for open data regarding land parcels (cadastral data) in Germany. I have found such datasets for other countries, like France, but I haven’t been able to locate similar data for Germany.
Are there any openly available datasets for German land parcels or cadastral maps?
If so, where can I access them?
If no open data is available, are there alternative options for obtaining this data, even if not free?

please ask on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

https://www.bezreg-koeln.nrw.de/geobasis-nrw/webdienste/geodatendienste
has parcel/plots as wfs > https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis

The keyword of your request would contain the word Flurstück, and I would suggest using this webpage: https://geoportal.de/Themen/Raum_und_Lage/3_Liegenschaften.html

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416072/accessing-inspire-cadastral-data-through-qgis
